# Origen de la expresión "talla" con el significado de "chiste"

Tags: etimología, modismos, chile

En Chile usamos abundantemente la palabra **talla** para referirnos a una frase espontánea que provoca risa. Puede decirse en lugar de *chiste*, *broma* y, a veces, de *situación graciosa*. Por ejemplo:

> ¡Qué buena la talla!  (Fue gracioso el chiste)
>
> Ser tallero o ser bueno pa' la talla. (Ser gracioso)
>
> Me pasó una talla. (Me ocurrió algo gracioso)

Me pregunto de dónde proviene este modismo y si se usa con el mismo significado en otros países.

Comment: Honestamente, este modismo es solo de los chilenos, aunque me sorprendería si supiese que se usa en otros lados.

Comment: En España desconocemos el uso de _talla_ con ese significado. Lo curioso es que la RAE no lo recoge, así que debe de ser de uso muy localizado en Chile. Sería interesante conocer de dónde proviene.

Comment: Por lo que veo es claramente un chilenismo. Lo refleja la siempre interesante página dechile.net en su sección [chilenismos](http://www.dechile.net/?chilenismos): _Chiste, broma, humorada_.

Comment: ¿Del inglés _tale_? Ni idea. Nunca la había oído...

Comment: @MikMik Qué perspicaz. Voy a buscar, a lo mejor viene por ahí.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Sí que está recogido [_tallero, ra_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Z0sC9U2): "adj. coloq. Chile. Que bromea aguda y oportunamente".

Comment: @cdlvcdlv anda, pues ya es curioso que esté recogido _tallero_ si no sabemos qué son las _tallas_ que dan origen al nombre de su "profesión"...

Comment: He buscado en muchos lugares y no he podido dar con el origen de la palabra. Quizás haya que hacer una investigación más exhaustiva y buscar en bibliotecas y archivos locales, o mejor aún intentar recoger testimonios. Yo recuerdo que cuando pequeño aprendí el origen de algunos modismos por medio de mi abuelo. Es una buena fuente de conocimiento preguntarle a la gente mayor. Si alguien tiene la posibilidad de hacerlo, adelante, yo intentaré hacer lo propio.

Comment: Tampoco la habia escuchado antes de esa manera. Alguna vez (muy poco, realmente)  en en mi pais se usa "Dio la talla", como para decir que destacó en algo: "Fulano dió la talla con un 10 en gimnasia", ó "Fulana dió la talla con su elegante y hermoso vestido". Algo así como en Inglés: "Set the bar".

Comment: En cuba se usa casi igual q en chile entonces, lo unico que si no habia visto es lo del tallero, pero por lo demas igual, asi como dice @DelonixR. , fulano dio la talla. A veces uno hace una histora y pasa algo sorprendente, tambien decimos `que talla mas loca`. [otro ejemplo en la prensa oficial](http://www.juventudrebelde.cu/cultura/2016-03-27/cuba-esta-en-talla/)

Comment: [La talla cubana y sus usos](http://www.cubanos.guru/la-talla-cubana-y-sus-usos/)

Comment: El termino de talla es utilizado en algunas areas de mexico, ea español antiguo y muy comunmente hablado por sefardies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aventuro este proceso de propagación de significados, que no encuentro descabellado.

La palabra que nos ocupa es [*talla*<sup>1</sup>](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=YzzJBPM), que proviene, según el DLE, de [*tallar*<sup>2</sup>](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=Z0NDGtY). Si observamos las acepciones 11 y 13 de este verbo...

> 11. intr. coloq. Intervenir en una conversación, y, por ext., en cualquier asunto.
> 12. (...)
> 13. intr. coloq. Destacar, dibujarse. U. t. c. tr. y c. prnl.

... y las cruzamos, nos queda un híbrido: "interrumpir una conversación de forma destacada". Es lo que ocurre cuando alguien caza al vuelo una frase y aprovecha una mínima pausa para terminarla, en un alarde de improvisación, de una manera inesperada: original, tajante, incisiva, elegante, profunda, subversiva... en resumen, brillante. Cuando eso ocurre, aunque la frase no sea humorística, los presentes no tienen más remedio que, al menos, sonreír (si no se ríen francamente). No es un significado nuevo, sino dos acepciones del verbo utilizadas de forma simultánea.

Ya que *talla* es el acto de *tallar*, que *talla* llegue desde ahí a "una frase espontánea que provoca risa" no hay ni siquiera un paso (tal vez medio). No es raro que acabe asociándose ese tipo de intervenciones al humor principalmente. Y una vez que *talla* es algo gracioso, este significado genera con naturalidad otros por contagio, como puede verse en el enlace de ["la talla cubana"](http://www.cubanos.guru/la-talla-cubana-y-sus-usos/) que nos daba Emilio.

Una vez hecha esa reflexión, cae por su propio peso el significado de [*tallero*](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=Z0sC9U2) que aparece en el DLE.

> 1. adj. coloq. Chile. Que bromea aguda y oportunamente.

Ser *tallero* sería, más que [*estar sembrado*](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=XViwgtq), serlo.

¿Por qué el verbo *tallar* y sus derivaciones se asocian con el ingenio? La etimología de este verbo nos dice:

> Del lat. vulg. taleāre 'cortar', 'rajar'...

Tallar es algo que se hace con herramientas afiladas y no es la única relación que existe (en español y en otros idiomas, como pasa con *sharp* en inglés) entre lo afilado y la inteligencia y el ingenio. Si repasáis este mismo texto, veréis que he utilizado las palabras *incisiva*, *tajante* y *aguda* de la forma más natural. Y es que el *tallero* "corta un pelo en el aire".

Comment: Hay un error en tu interpretación de la acepción 13 del verbo `tallar`. `Destacar` o `dibujarse` se refiere al acto de tallar una figura, no al de destacarse en el sentido de sobresalir.

Comment: Además, considero que el hecho de que la palabra *tallero* aparezca en el DLE no da indicio de su origin. La palabra fue agregada debido a su uso extensivo en un determinado país, no al revés. En lo personal creo que el origen de la palabra, con el significado que se la da en Chile, viene desde lo popular.

Answer (score 2):

De donde proviene no sé, supongo que una talla es una medida o algo medible y de ahí a que se use para medir lo que te provoca la expresión, ya sea alegría, sorpresa, etc. Supongo que sea por ahí la cosa.

Pero lo que sí sé es que en Cuba se usa exactamente para lo mismo.
Ejemplo:

> ¡¡Mira esta talla!! = Mira esto que bueno está
>
> ¡¡Tremenda talla!! = Pasó algo sorprendente (ya sea bueno o malo)
>
> !Qué clase de talla! = (igual que el anterior)

Comment: Interesante; y yo que creía que solamente era válida para Chile.

Comment: @Alejandro Con la diferencia de que en Cuba se usa no solo para un chiste o algo gracioso, se usa tanto para algo bueno que ocurrió o algo malo. Y también, sin necesidad de ser bueno o malo sino algo que simplemente te sorprendió. Que clase de talla! - es como "Wow!!"

Answer (score 2):

Las tallas no son exclusivas de Chile. Esta palabra se usa en Panamá, Costa Rica, México, Cuba, Chile y otros países.

Mi nombre es César Samudio, de Chiriquí, república de Panamá. Soy autor del libro *Tallas Chiricanas*.

Comment: Encantado, César, y bienvenido al sitio. Muchas gracias por su respuesta acerca de la palabra "talla", es sin duda de gran utilidad. Sin embargo, la parte de la promoción de su libro en este sitio está de más. Normalmente las respuestas que incluyen cualquier tipo de promoción suelen ser eliminadas, por lo que le rogamos que elimine esa parte junto con sus datos de contacto (que, por otro lado, pueden ser utilizados por rastreadores automáticos para enviarle correo no deseado o recibir llamadas o mensajes no deseados).

Comment: ¿Hay algunos libros de este tema en Chile?

Answer (score 0):

Yo conocía el uso de “talla” a un chiste largo con un principio, acompañado de una serie de aventuras o episodios referentes al personaje, y finalmente un remate corto y gracioso. Dichos episodios eran controlados por el cómico y podía hacer tan largo o corto como quisiera, es decir, a la medida, o a la “talla” del público.

En referencia de tiempo y espacio la ubicación sería en México, en los 90s.

Answer (score 0):

Mi hija de 8 años tuvo la inquietud del origen de la palabra. Y acá llegamos; tremendamente agradecidos de haber aprendido algo nuevo hoy en familia. Los 4 de este clan enviamos saludos desde Chile

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/26088)