# How to translate "raw format"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, informática

I was [reviewing a post](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17495/1674) when I noticed that it contained some (to me) garbled codes due to copy pasting from a web page.

I decided to get the raw text to get rid of such codes, and so I did. However, then I kept asking to myself:

**What is a good translation in Spanish of *raw format*?**

Would "formato crudo" sound that bad? What about "formato puro" as this is one of the [possible translations of *raw* that WordReference suggests](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=raw)?

Comment: La respuesta me ha salido sola en español, @fedorqui, pero es que nos conocemos ya y sabemos de dónde somos. ¿Querías la respuesta en inglés? Es que me lío un poco porque pensaba que en Spanish Language se intentaba promover el uso del español...

Comment: Intento intercalar alguna pregunta en inglés, sobre todo aquellas que son del tipo traducción. Mi opinión es que (además de practicar el inglés, que siempre va bien) esto puede acercar el sitio a más gente, especialmente aquella que no está tan metida en el castellano y puede buscar la traducción a conceptos relativamente básicos. Si no, tengo el miedo de que este sitio sea para apenas un puñado de usuarios muy activos, pero pocos, con lo que nos acabaremos estancando.

Comment: Me parece que la dificultad de obtener una traducción 'perfecta' estriba en la particularidad que cada idioma tiene de expresar mejor ciertos eventos, objetos o circunstancias. En este caso, cuando en ingles decimos "raw data" ambos interlocutores saben exactamente de lo que se habla. En Español cuesta encontrar un equivalente en palabras pues la particularidad del idioma hace que nuestras palabras puedan tener acepciones diferentes, o interpretaciones diferentes. Creo que ademas es debido a que "raw data" es un termino técnico. Espero que el comentario no esté muy fuera de lugar/ _off topic_

Comment: "sin formato" 
"puro"  
son las formas en las que se utilizaria 

para "raw data" utilizarias :"informacion pura sin formato"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### ENGLISH

*Raw* can be translated to [*en bruto*](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?val=en+bruto).

> 1. loc. adj. Sin pulir o labrar.

Which is the same as unprocessed ("sin elaborar").

### ESPAÑOL

*Raw* puede traducirse también por [*en bruto*](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?val=en+bruto).

> 1. loc. adj. Sin pulir o labrar.

Sería equivalente a "sin elaborar".

Comment: Siempre hemos hablado de "diamantes en bruto" que también en inglés se llaman "raw diamonds" por lo que me voy con ésta: "Datos en bruto"

Comment: Since @fedorqui wanted the answer written in English... here we go ;-)

Comment: @DGaleano Gracias. Creía que otra vez no funcionaban los enlaces, porque había puesto el correspondiente a _en bruto_ en el DLE y no lo veía, pero era que olvidé poner el "http://".

Comment: raw format es traducido a "sin formato" en terminos computacionales

Answer (score 2):

Últimamente con tantas elecciones en España se han realizado muchas encuestas y barómetros, siendo los del [CIS](http://www.cis.es/) (Centro de Investigaciones Sociológicas) de los más mencionados. Muchas noticias hacían referencia a que el CIS realiza un procesamiento de los datos antes de publicar los resultados, y se puso de moda el concepto de ***datos cocinados***, en contraposición a los ***datos en crudo***, que son los que se obtienen tal cual de las encuestas.

La verdad es que hablar de "formato crudo" o "datos crudos" no me termina de sonar bien del todo, pero sí que me suena mejor hablar de "datos en crudo" o "en bruto". Como curiosidad, esto es lo que dice Ngram al respecto, ya de paso llevándome la contraria:

[image: datos brutos]

Por cierto, y ya aparte, si lo que copiaste fue código HTML, lo que tú querías era el "texto *renderizado*" tras interpretar el código, que podría dar para otra pregunta...

Comment: Uhms, interesante. De hecho, lo que quería en este caso es puramente el texto _plano_, sin que ninguna de las pijadillas de HTML aparecieran.

Comment: "raw format" es un término común en fotografia digital, pero no así en informatica. En este último se utiliza  "ascii format", o como @fedorqui indica, __plain text__ para indicar que los datos son solo texto y no llevan ningun otro tipo de comando o codigo asociado a programas que manejan o procesan esos datos (htlm, excel, dbf, etc). En esta pregunta concreta, __plain text__ en lugar de raw format hubiese sido mas acertado.

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que es dependiente del contexto. En el que nos ocupa, esos códigos son llamados con **código fuente** ([source code](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_Code)).

**Formato crudo** es la expresión que he visto con cierta regularidad para referirse a "Raw Format", en contextos como la forma de almacenamiento de una imagen digital. Pero es más habitual, por mucho, decir "formato raw", aunque sea incluso técnicamente incorrecto.

Considero que surge algún tipo de incompatibilidad entre "format" y "raw" a pesar de su extendido uso conjunto en inglés. Dado que "raw", como bien mencionaron en otras respuestas (en bruto, sin elaborar, sin procesar) no puede por definición estar formateado (que implica cierta organización o disposición ordenada/sistematizada de algo). Especulo que eso podría ser el origen de la dificultad para la traducción.

"Formato puro" no es una expresión que me suene familiar ni correcta para ese fin. En todo caso sí sería correcto decir "... formato $X$ puro.", entendiendo a "puro" como "estricto", en el sentido que se apega a todas las reglas del formato $X$. Donde $X$ sería el nombre que recibe algún conjunto de reglas de sintaxis .

Answer (score 0):

Se puede traducir como "crudo", "sin hacer", "sin elaborar".

"This meat is raw" -> "Esta comida está cruda".